# Not able to split input string from the given format in c?

Tags: c, strtok

I was trying to take out individual digits from input string like **1 2 3 4,5 6 7 8,9 10 11 12** in c program by splitting using **strtok()** function. For this i wrote below programming but it was reading till first comma **,** delimiter( Note : input size can vary. like in given example comma is after 4 digits but it can be after k(5,6,7, etc) digits based on give testcases ).

```
 fgets(str,80,stdin);

 /* read str with comma(,)delimiter  */
 token = strtok(str, ","); 

 /* walk through other tokens */
  while( token != NULL ) 
   {

       // read token string with space delimiter 
       token2 = strtok(token, " ");
       while( token2 != NULL ) 
       {
            printf("%s \n", token2);    
            token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
       }

      token = strtok(NULL, ",");
   }
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with the result of the some of the `strtok` calls, and you are passing the wrong pointer argument. You should make repeat calls with a  `NULL` pointer, until `strtok` itself returns `NULL`. Aside: you must add `\n` to the delimiter string since `fgets` retains a trailing `newline`.

Comment: What is the expected output of a simple test program which processes the input stated? Each digit, each number, each group, their sum? It's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtok` is not reentrant -- you can only tokenize one string at a time.  If you want to simultaneously tokenize multiple strings at a time, use `strtok_r` instead.  Better yet, ALWAYS use `strtok_r` in preference to `strtok`, as it is never less capable:

```
char *inner, *outer;
fgets(str,80,stdin);

/* read str with comma(,)delimiter  */   
token = strtok_r(str, ",", &outer);

/* walk through other tokens */
while( token != NULL ) 
{

    // read token string with space delimiter 
    token2 = strtok_r(token, " ", &inner);
    while( token2 != NULL ) 
    {
        printf("%s \n", token2);    
        token2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &inner);
    }

    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &outer);
}
```

You might also want to investigate `strsep` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `strtok` works with the last string that was passed to it that was not NULL.

Hence, the line:

```
token = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

does not work.

If you know the exact number of tokens, you can use `sscanf`.

```
/* read str with comma(,)delimiter  */
token = strtok(str, ","); 

/* walk through other tokens */
while( token != NULL ) 
{
   int num1;
   int num2;
   int num3;
   int num4;

   if ( sscanf(token, "%d %d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4) != 4 )
   {
      // Problem.
   }
   else
   {
      // Use the numbers
   }

   token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

Comment: if we don't know exact number of digits in each token, how to use sscnaf to get all digits?

Comment: @BalaKrishna please explain clearly what you mean by "total input" by editing the question - not in comments.